# How to select an element in a browser using its title in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click on the button in a webpage using its title, in Java using selenium webdriver. How can I do it?

The html is like this:

```
<td>
   <input type="text" value=""
      id="14611txnId" name="txnId"
      style="width: 250px;" placeholder="Enter TransactionId"
      readonly="true">
   <button type="button" title="Enter TxnID"
      id="14611addTxnid"
      onclick="javascript:enableInputForEdit('14611')"
      class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Edit</button>
   <button type="button" title="Save TxnID"
      id="14611SaveTxnid"
      style="display: none"
      onclick="javascript:saveTxnId('14611','MD-PE_02')"
      class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Save</button>
</td>
```

I need to click on the first button. How can I do it using title?

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: do you mean you need your title to clickable like a button ?

Comment: Do you mean title property or text of the button?

Comment: @hatched not like that i need to click on the button using the property title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Enter TxnID']"));
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("14611addTxnid"));
```

Comment: since there are lots of buttons and every button id are different(like 14611addTxnid,14612addTxnid etc.. ) so cannot specify the exact id. so i need a method which will select it using the title.

Comment: @rakesh, Refer my updated answer for title attribute

Comment: @Ishitha ,Thanks can you please tell me that i am storing the web element till div in a variable row and then using row.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Enter TxnID']")).click();  will it work?? or i need to use row.findElement(By.xpath("/button[@title='Enter TxnID']")).click();   ?

Comment: @Ishitha what is the difference between single / and double // ?

Comment: Its xpath syntax to define node with //(Double)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 2):

You can use css-selectors:

```
WebElement button = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title=\"yourtitle\"]"));
```

Where `yourtitle` is the title of the element you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to click on it by using cssSelector to locate a button with a specific text, like this:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[title*='ButtonText']")).click();
```

The * sign indicates that webDriver will find a `button` with attribute `title` that contains the text "ButtonText".

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't looks like locating element *by title*

Comment: Yes, I know :). But as he stated that he wants to click on 1st button, so this can be an option, to rid of static Text

Comment: actually, i need to use title property. since there are lots of buttons. like this.

Comment: @rakesh OK, I see. I updated my answer. Hope it helps :)